# Is it possible to add code highlighting function to Excel's connection properties window

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wonder whether one can somehow "customize" Excel's connection properties windows. For example I would like to have SQL syntax highlighting. 
Would something like that be possible via VBA?
Or can the vanilla properties window be replaced with a third party form/UI?

[picture of the properties windows i am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Fj7.png)
[image]

Comment: Built-in window have no such possibility. You may create your own addon with custom form, and use some third-party highlighting module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer